# Subtracting the values in two rows using Awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I’m new to awk and I’m trying to learn bash on my own, I find awk really interesting and I’m just wondering how I would subtract the values of two rows

```
34 43 67 87
21 22 64 43
```

such that I reach a desired output of

```
13 21 3 44
```

my attempt at it

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = "\n" }{avgShirts=$1-$2}{print avgShirts}'
```

Since its only two rows I tried by specifying that the field seperator is a new line but it didnt work.

Comment: `"\n"` is typically used as a row/record separator; the default field separator is white space (ie, a space or tab)

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions/understanding:

- input consists of exactly 2 rows
- both rows have the same number of fields/columns

Input:

```
$ cat 2rows.dat
34 43 67 87
21 22 64 43
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)            # 1st line, loop through each field and ...
            fld[i]=$i                  # store each field in array fld[]
        next                           # skip the rest of the awk script and proceed to the next input line
      }
      { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {          # 2nd line, loop through each field and ...
            line=line pfx (fld[i]-$i)  # build output line based on difference of fields from 1st and 2nd lines
            pfx=OFS                    # 1st pass through loop pfx="", rest of loop pfx=" "
        }
        print line                     # print line of differences
      }
' 2rows.dat
```

This generates:

```
13 21 3 44
```

---

An alternate `awk` idea that prints the sums as they're calculated:

```
awk '
NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            fld[i]=$i
        next
      }
      { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s%s", pfx, (fld[i]-$i)   # print prefix and current diff, since there is no "\n" we remain on the same output line for the next pass through the loop
            pfx=OFS
        }
        print ""                              # terminate line; same effect as: printf "\n"
      }
' 2rows.dat
```

This also generates:

```
13 21 3 44
```

Comment: what does the pfx do and whats the OFS?

Comment: `pfx` is just my abbreviation for 'prefix', `OFS` is the default output field separator of a single space; first time through `line` and `pfx` are empty so `line=line pfx (fld[i]-$i)` is the same as `line=(fld[i]-$i)`; if `pfx=OFS` on the first pass then the output line would have a leading space

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
awk 'FNR%2{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) arr[i]=$i; next}
     {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=arr[i]-$i} 1' file
13 21 3 44
```

Explanation:

```
# save every odd line 
FNR%2{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) arr[i]=$i; next}

# every even line, subtract this field from the previous and print 
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=arr[i]-$i} 1'
```

Comment: do you mind explaining why NR==1 and NR==2 instead of odd and even wouldnt work because I tried them and it didnt

Comment: If I replace `FNR%2` with `NR==1` it works the same. Note that `NR` is total records, and `FNR` is the record of the file...

Comment: what does the 1 do, if you dont mind explaining at the end ?

Comment: `1` evaluates to true. Anything 'truthy` causes awk to print as a default or do the action inside of `{action}` In this case, a stand alone `1` causes print.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    NR==1 { split($0,minuends); next }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%d%s", minuends[i] - $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' file
13 21 3 44
```

If you're new to awk then look up NR, NF, OFS, ORS, and split() in the man page. You can learn awk from the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.